# Нужна ли запятая после "так же"? И "так же" раздельно в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация

Его это все не волновало, так же как и меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Его это все не волновало, **так же как и** меня.

В данном предложении **нет расчленения союза**, частица ЖЕ пишется раздельно. Это составной союз ***ТАК ЖЕ КАК И***.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_738

Им ничего не нужно было от своих бывших учеников, так же как и тем от своих бывших учителей. Д. Гранин, Зубр.

**Но:** От тяжелой росистой травы кругом и от цветов, ночных цветов, только теперь раскрывших свои головки, пахло **так же, как** от волос Анны. Наталья обращалась с ним точно **так же, как и** прежде. И. Тургенев, Рудин.

Эта же тема рассмотрена у Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:

2) если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово  (так, такой, тот, столь):  Всё вокруг какое-то церковное, и маслом пахнет **так же крепко, как в церкви** (М. Г.); …
Но: Наша группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, **так же как параллельная** — без расчленения сложного союза;